# Accessing a firefox addon's functions from a simple website

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

is it possible to have a library of functions in an AddOn, let's say we have:

```
notification(str){
    $('#notification').text(str);
}
```

how could i access that function from a default html website ?

thx :)

Comment: The addon has to enable the website to interact with it. Can't be done the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `exportFunction`.

```
notification(str){
    $('#notification').text(str);
}

exportFunction(notification, contentWindow, {
  defineAs: "addonNotification"
});
```

Then from the web page, use `window.addonNotification("hello notification!")`

For more information:

- https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.exportFunction